# In Snowflake sql can we call a Oracle's Sequence function

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake sql can we call a Oracle's Sequence function just like how we can do a look up in Pentaho and use the Oracle sequence generator. Is it possible in Snowflake ?

Comment: Can you add more context? Sample code? Desired results?

Comment: You can't use *Oracles* sequence function but you can use Snowflakes. Documented really well here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences.html

Comment: @FelipeHoffa: I have 2 different systems A and B. A is the target Oracle system, I'm getting records from B transforming it into A's table structure and loading. But a columns called account_id is a sequence generated in A, I want to use the same everytime I load from B so the sequence is not missed. This is done in Pentaho, can it similarly be done in Snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you may use Snowflake's Sequence feature, see below links.

CREATE SEQUENCE: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-sequence.html

Querying sequences: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences.html

But you have to be beware of possible differences. For example is it possible to use CURRVALL in Oracle to extract the current value. This is not implemented in Snowflake.